# How to make a div take all the remaining height

Tags: html, css, height, positioning

There is a lot of topics like this but none have the answer I need

I have this kind of HTML/CSS code

```
<style>
#container {width:300px;height:290px;background:yellow;}
#up {width:100%;float:left;background:green;}
#up2 {width:100%;float:left;background:blue;}
#down {height:100%;background:pink;overflow: hidden;float:left;}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="up">asd<br>asd</div>
    <div id="up2">asd<br>asd</div>
    <div id="down">
        <span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sagittis, nisl non dignissim porttitor, nulla metus pretium massa, non pretium ligula tellus sed justo. Donec quis justo lectus. Pellentesque sagittis egestas metus eget pharetra. Phasellus cursus libero dui, nec scelerisque elit lobortis ut. Mauris quis nunc sit amet purus fringilla ullamcorper. Mauris eget rutrum sem. Phasellus molestie enim at tellus imperdiet, ut venenatis justo rhoncus.
 consequat tortor ornare tempus.
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need `#down` to take all remaining space after `#up` and `#up2`

`#up` and `#up2` don't have fixed height (there is a lot of solutions if they have fixed height but I didn't find solutions if height is dynamic)

text in `#down` can be large than block itself, so it should be hidden with `overflow:hidden`

`<span>` inside `#down` is required

Comment: i think you only can do this with JS....

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/jUy8B/ or do you want the height to be the size of the text (which can change)?

Comment: I'd probably use JavaScript to do the calculation for this. Don't think it can be done otherwise. I always like to be suprised though :)

Comment: I have a pure CSS solution for you. I'll post an answer shortly..

Comment: @lhan16 - downHeight = containerHeigh - (upHeight + up2Height)
span inside #down can go outside of it, overflow: hidden will hide it, but #down should not

Comment: I think you will need to use Javascript to do that.

Answer (score 0):

add :

```
html, body {
    height:100%;  /* <-- this is missing*/
    width:100%;  /* <-- this is missing*/

}
#container {
    width:300px;
    min-height:290px; /* <-- this is missing*/
    background:yellow;
    height:100%; /* <-- this is missing*/
}
```

<kbd>[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ughnw/1/)</kbd>

**EDIT**

**CSS**

```
#down {
    height:100%;
    max-height:290px; /* <-- this is missing*/
    background:pink;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
}
```

<kbd>[**2nd demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ughnw/2/)</kbd>

Comment: container height should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qs4LV/1/) is a Pure CSS solution:

I'm using pseudo elements to make the div take the remaining container space.
I'll provide an explanation of how it works if you'll want one.

**CSS:** (I've cleaned out some of your CSS)

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container
{
    background-color: black;
    height: 500px; /*Or any other fix height*/
}
#container:before  /* <--- new */
{
    content: '';
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
#up
{
    background:green;
}
#up2
{
    background:blue;
}
#down
{
    background:pink;
}
#down:after /* <--- new */
{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: in this example #down resizes if text is too large
please look here http://jsfiddle.net/Qs4LV/2/ I have modified your fiddle a bit, just changed sizes to what I need and added more text

Comment: You want the text to be hidden? if so: use `overflow:hidden;` on the `#container` like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qs4LV/3/)

Comment: I need overflow:hidden on #down not on container, the height of #down is used in javascript to calculate chars count, JS cuts the text to fit it in visible area of #down div, in your example the last line is half visible, I'm using JS to avoid that kind of situations